# Regular expression to exclude local addresses

Tags: regex

I'm trying to configure my Foxy Proxy program and one of the features is to provide a regular expression for an exclusion list.
I'm trying to blacklist the local sites (ending in .local), but it doesn't seem to work.
This is what I attempted:

```
^(?:https?://)?\d+\.(?!local)+/.*$
^(?:https?://)?\d+\.(?!local)(\d)+/.*$
```

I also researched on Google and Stack Exchange with no success.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a url you are trying to blacklist?  Your example is checking for the `.local` part before the end of the string.

Comment: If everything ending in `.local` should be blacklisted, why wouldn't something like `^http.+\.local$` be enough? Can you give examples, what you want to match/don't match?

Comment: Thanks Jonny 5, I tried that, but doesn't work. Actually this has to "whitelist" every site not ending in .local. Bare in mind that the site can have a long url which I have to account for. So     http://mysite.local/index.php?params=2&other=1 I want to allow for instance http://facebook.com but not http://facebook.local. I hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: Did I get it right [from the manual](http://getfoxyproxy.org/patterns.html) that the pattern must start with `^` and end with `$` to be recognized as regex pattern? Then for the blacklist, would `^(https?://)?[^/]+\.local([/?]?|[/?].*)$` maybe meet your requirements?

Comment: No, you don't have to add them, it just says that if you want their functionality, you have to add them manually. Also, I don't see the point of the alternation in that regular expression, can't it be replaced by `([/?].*)?` ?

Comment: @BartEnkelaar Yea Bart, it's the same. So `^(https?://)?[^/]+\.local([/?].*)?$` should be fine for the **blacklist**, what do you think?

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine for a blacklist, but I think he actually has a whitelist, which is why I provided a whitelist solution. I assumed there always were forward slashes in the URL's as the Regular Expressions in the question assume that as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you indicate in the comments that you actually need a whitelist solution, I went with that:

Try: `^(?:https?://)?[\w.-]+\\.(?!local)\w+/.*$`

http://regex101.com/r/xV4gS0

Comment: Maybe add, that it's a **whitelist** solution. Wasn't sure yet, if the used regex-engine supports lookarounds, but should be fine, as it [obviously uses](http://getfoxyproxy.org/mozilla/faq.html) [JavaScript 1.5 regular expression syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). And wrap that beast in backticks maybe for better reading.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex expressions match host names which start with a series of digits followed by a period and then *not* followed by the string "local". If this is a "blacklist", then that hardly seems like what you want.

If you're trying to match all hostnames which end in `.local`, you'd want something like the following for the hostname portion:

```
[^/]*\.local(?:/|$)
```

with appropriate escapes inserted depending on regex context.

If your original question was incorrect and you really need a whitelist, then you'd want something like:

```
^(?:(?!\.local)[^\/])*(?:\/|$)
```

as illustrated in http://regex101.com/r/yB0uY4

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone to help. Indeed, it turns out that for this program, enlisting "not `.local`" as blacklist, it's not the same as "all `.local`" as whitelist. 
I also had a rookie mistake on my pattern. I meant `"\w"` instead of `"\d"`. Thank you Peter Alfvin for catching that.
So my final working solution is what Bart suggested:

```
^(?:https?://)?[\w.-]+\.(?!local)\w+/.*$ as a whitelist.
```